# Orcad: less than 2 connections on the emitter of the PN2222

Tags: simulation, error, orcad, common-collector

[image]

I keep getting an error while simulating concerning the emitter node. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the error? ... please copy the error and paste it into your post

Comment: Anyway, it should be "fewer than.."